# C# how can I get generic class reference at method

Tags: c#, oop

I have model to get head field and generic type data.

```
public class RootApiModel<T> where T : class
{
    public string @event { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string signature { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public T data { get; set; }
}
```

My problem that , I'm checking required fields at the `RequiredFieldsControl` class.For the code to be unrepeated ,I want to check head control and generic data control separately.But I don't know , how can I get reference for `HeadRequiredFields` method ?

```
"RootApiModel<object> item"
```

or

```
"RootApiModel<T> item"
```

I am getting the can not convert warning

```
 public static class RequiredFieldsControl
{
    private static void HeadRequiredFields(RootApiModel<object> item)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.@event))
            throw new Exception("Event Alanı Zorunludur");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.timestamp))
            throw new Exception("Timestamp Alanı Zorunludur");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.token))
            throw new Exception("Token Alanı Zorunludur");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.signature))
            throw new Exception("Signature Alanı Zorunludur");

        if (item.status <= 0)
            throw new Exception("Status Alanı Zorunludur");
    }
    public static void BuildingControl(RootApiModel<BuildingApiModel> buildingItem)
    {
        HeadRequiredFields(buildingItem);

        if (buildingItem.data.ReferenceID<=0)
            throw new Exception("BuildingReferenceID Alanı Zorunludur");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(buildingItem.data.BuildingName))
            throw new Exception("BuildingName Alanı Zorunludur");
    }

    public static void BlockControl(RootApiModel<BlockApiModel> blockItem)
    {
        HeadRequiredFields(blockItem);

        if (blockItem.data.BuildingReferenceID <= 0)
            throw new Exception("BuildingReferenceID Alanı Zorunludur");

        if (blockItem.data.BlockReferenceID <= 0)
            throw new Exception("BlockReferenceID Alanı Zorunludur");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(blockItem.data.BlockName))
            throw new Exception("BlockName Alanı Zorunludur");
    }

}
```

Comment: Make your `HeadRequiredFields` generic. Add `<T>` to the definition of the method and use that instead of `<object>`.

Comment: "It does not work" is not a valid problem-description. What does this mean? Exceptions? Unexpected results?

Comment: ok ,I've edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HeadRequiredFields should probably look something like:

```
private static void HeadRequiredFields<T>(RootApiModel<T> item)  where T : class
```

This will limit `<T>` to be reference types, so value types will not be allowed.

Comment: I did what you said ,but now I am getting this warning  "The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use 
it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 
'RootApiModel<T>'" at the  HeadRequiredFields<T>(RootApiModel<T> item)  on item